# Запись и чтение сообщений без блокировки в многопоточном приложении

Tags: c++

Имеется приложение многопоточное. Каждый поток получает одни и те же данные. Это сообщения, и у каждого сообщения есть свой айди. Один поток получает их чуть быстрее, а другой - чуть медленнее. Необходимо сохранять сообщения из разных потоков без блокировок, брать нужно только самое первое сообщение для данного айди. Известно, что все потоки получают сообщения последовательно, айди всегда идут строго по возрастанию и всегда начиная с айди, равного нулю.

Вопрос - как это можно реализовать без блокировок?

Вопрос с собеседования по С++ в компанию, которая работает в сфере High Frequency Trading

Comment: Ну например Facebook/folly AtomicHashMap. Именно для этой цели я его и использую, Нраица.

Comment: @gbg а немогли бы Вы пояснить на каких принципах работает это контейнер, за счет чего достигается отсутствие блокировок?

Comment: Для начала стоило бы привести свой вариант, как в прочих вопросах на учебные темы. Ну и в условии не поясняется, что именно подразумевается под *"без блокировок"*, поэтому вряд ли стоит ожидать какого-то вразумительного ответа.

Comment: @user7860670, а мне вот задание вполне ясно - нужно решить задачу без использования std::mutex. Какие могут быть альтернативы?

Comment: а правильно ли я понимаю задачу, что это классический consumer-producer, то только читателей несколько. И сообщение нужно удалять только тогда, когда все его прочитали?

Comment: @gbg В зависимости от содержания требования "без блокировок", задача вполне может решатся и с использованием мьютексов. С другой стороны, использование контейнера с `Atomic` в названии само по себе не обязательно поможет в соблюдении этих требований. Собственно заявление вида что что-то становится неблокирующим, так как там используется не мьютексы, а атомарные операции, скорее годится для булщит бинго. Я подобное задание воспринимаю прежде всего в свете определения ограничений в работе приложения.

Comment: Да, задание плохое, что с головой выдает средний уровень того, кто эту задачу придумал - потому что требование реально должно звучать как "время отклика X микросекунд на 30k CPS", а как подопытный этого будет добиваться - его дело.

С другой стороны. Возможно, постановщику задания нужно проверить именно понимание разницы между мьютексы / не-мьютексы (например, уже есть тонна кода, написанная без мьютексов, и в ней нужно разбираться).

Если все задачи будут поставлены качественно, программистов можно будет спокойно отправлять на покой. (Хорошая постановка задачи зачастую и есть решение).

Comment: я думаю, что задача была поставлена нормально. Просто мы ее видим через призму понимания вопрошающего. я просто даже вижу мелкие грамматические несостыковки в формулировке

Answer (score 2):

Ну например [Facebook/folly AtomicHashMap](https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/master/folly/docs/AtomicHashMap.md).

Этот контейнер повторяет во многом семантику `std::map`, так что аналогично `std::map` вы можете использовать в нем метод `insert`, который будет либо помещать новый айдишник в контейнер, либо возвращать результат, показывающий, что айдишник в контейнере уже имеется.

Идея, заложенная в этот контейнер называется общим термином [Lock-Free](https://habr.com/ru/company/wunderfund/blog/322094/).

Дело в том, что традиционные блокировки на мьютексах слишком дороги по времени, особенно на всевозможных системах с NUMA и подобных.

Поэтому, на передный план выходят атомарные операции с переменными (надеюсь, из названия понятно, что это такое), а также операции с семантикой [Compare-And-Swap](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC) (Атомарно сравнить значение в памяти с аргументом A и в случае совпадения, заменить его аргументом B)

Внутри AtomicHashMap сидит как раз такая сложная конструкция-индекс, для модификации которой и используются эти примитивы.

Если еще подумать над вашей задачей, может оказаться, что ее можно решить и без сторонней помощи, опираясь как раз на факт монотонного роста айдишников сообщений и операцию CAS

Comment: Минусующие по традиции приглашаются в комментарии с аргументами.

Comment: я, как обычно, не минусовал, но подозреваю, что автору нужна очередь FIFO, а в ответе предлагается мапа. Что явно не то.

Comment: "Нужно только самое первое сообщение для данного айди" - я так понял, что сообщение с идентичным ID может приехать и потоку A и потоку B, так вот кому первому пришло, тот и вставляет.

Формулировочка задания конечно довольно размытая, что позволяет интервьюру [отодвигать ворота](https://ru.rationalwiki.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8) в любом желаемом направлении

Comment: Очередность в мапе сохраняется в виду того, что индексы на входе идут подряд.

Comment: даже если Ваше предположение верно, все таки мапа далеко не самое лучше решение в данном случае. Хотя я могу и сильно-сильно ошибаться.

Comment: Вот вы предлагаете folly/AtomicHashMap. ¿А вас не смущает, что это далеко не универсальный контейнер: только 32-х 64-х битные атомарные ключи, нет поддержки удаления, а рост контейнера - блокирующая операция? Также для обеспечения условия "без блокировок" ему должно соответствовать и само сохранение.

Comment: О,  вы прочитали мануал на контейнер! А вы с его помощью код писали, отлаживали?

Ну так вот. Размер контейнера можно задать априори, и если его хорошо угадать, он не будет расти - следовательно, блокировка не случится. То есть, контейнер не растет на каждую вставку.

Далее. Сама вставка происходит с гарантией атомарности. Другое дело, что после вставки в другой поток может прилететь указатель на еще не созданный объект, но для данной задачи это не важно, потому что тут требуется отсекать дубли в ключах.

Что касается размера ключей - в задаче про них ничего не сказано.

Comment: Обсуждение таких плохо поставленных заданий всегда превращяется в конный цирк - каждый участник, прочитав ответ оппонента, быстренько находит в нем фатальный недостаток (обоже, а вдруг у нас будет строка вместо ключа!), дальше можно повысить ставки (да я на вашу строку md4 положу!), потом еще повысить (да ваше md4 будет кидать коллизии раз в миллион лет). 

И продолжать такой спор можно до бесконечности.

Comment: @gbg, я правильно уловил, что в этом контейнере используется  spinoff-mutex в user space вместо обращения к ядру?

Comment: @avp - там все несколько сложнее, чем спинлок в user-space.

Comment: @gbg, ну там и навалено всего в одну кучу. В конце-концов мне надоело искать реализацию tryLockCell()...

Comment: @avp - нажимаете на гитхабе точку и попадаете в IDE. tryLockCell один раз пытается сделать compareExchange, никакого верчения на спинлоке в ней не происходит

Comment: @gbg, меня название ввело в заблуждение. Назвали бы `tryToSet` (по смыслу алгоритма там как раз и надо вставлять key), наверное не стал бы долго искать. (а вот никакой точки и IDE (если бы я еще ими пользовался...) я чего-то там не нашел)

Comment: @avp - [открываете](https://github.dev/facebook/folly/blob/master/folly/MPMCQueue.h) и давите английскую точку. Должно сработать, при условии что вы залогинились на гитхаб.

Comment: @gbg, понятно, я не логинился, а просто перешел отсюда по ссылке